# Installing Imagick extension on PHP 7 nightly on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, imagick

I have ImageMagick installed and this, plus the Imagick extension, was working fine in PHP 5.6. Currently using the PHP 7 nightly build on Ubuntu 14.04, installed as per: http://php7.zend.com/

I understand there are compatibility issues, so I have found this https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/tree/phpseven and have attempted to install it, basically with:

`phpize
./configure
make
make install`

I then copy the imagick.so file to the extensions_dir and add it to php.ini and restarted Apache. Unfortunately, this isn't working - Imagick doesn't appear in phpinfo.

Does anyone know how to get this working with PHP 7?

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't give up my friend, PHP 5.6 is horrendously insecure.

Comment: That should work....if it's not there is something going wrong (duh), but we won't be able to tell what without more info. Are you sure you've edited the correct ini file? If you are, you might need to either turn on extra logging, or run Apache through strace to find what error is occuring.

Comment: Ah, I think I've seen the error now. On PHP startup this is logged: `Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20151012
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: You have PHP 5.x on that system as well, and the phpize used the 5.x binary not the one from php 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I did make some pretty basic mistakes here, though hopefully not obscure enough that the eventual solution won't help some people in the future.

The first issue was that I was indeed running phpize from PHP 5 - I thought I had symlinked this properly but I hadn't.

So aside from that, he first command to run was:

`/usr/local/php7/bin/phpize`

My second mistake was that ./configure also assumed I was running PHP 5, so to correct this I had to run:

`./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php7/bin/php-config`

Finally, `make` and `make install` worked and copied the files to the correct location automatically.

Thank you @Danack for your comments, they helped!

Comment: can you please tell us properly step by step , how did you get it working with php 7. i am a newb too. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this guide: [Install Imagick 3.4.0 on PHP 7.0 server - imagick-3.4.0-PHP7-forge.sh](https://gist.github.com/pascalbaljet/bd7b8fd63b76c7564189)
 (Laravel Forge). It worked fine for me. In case the link breaks:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

apt-get install pkg-config libmagickwand-dev -y
cd /tmp
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.4.0.tgz
tar xvzf imagick-3.4.0.tgz
cd imagick-3.4.0
phpize
./configure
make install
rm -rf /tmp/imagick-3.4.0*
echo extension=imagick.so >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
echo extension=imagick.so >> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
service php7.0-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```